# "No such entity with cartID = null" in the checkout after logged in on the other tab

Tags: checkout, magento2.4.0

The checkout stopped working after logging in on another browser's tab.

Scenario:

1. Fill the cart and proceed to the checkout page.
2. Go to the other browser's tab and logged in there.
3. Go back to the checkout on the first tab and try to complete the order.

Result: Magento says "No such entity with cartID = null".

see https://youtu.be/CEDZWR1Nj5U

It's normal behavior? I understand that the cart on the first tab is deactivated after logging in, however, I would expect that the checkout page will be refreshed after trying some action on the deactivated cart. Is there some solution how to avoid this?

Comment: No it's not normal behavior there is something wrong with your Magento

Comment: Check for extensions or customizations: If you have recently installed any third-party extensions or made customizations to your Magento 2 installation, they might be causing conflicts. Disable any recently installed extensions temporarily and test the checkout process again to see if the error persists.

Comment: The behavior you're experiencing is expected in Magento. When a customer logs in from another browser tab or session, it invalidates the cart associated with the previous session, which leads to the "No such entity with cartID = null" error when trying to complete the order.

By design, Magento doesn't automatically refresh the checkout page or prompt the user to update their cart after logging in from another session. This behavior helps prevent potential conflicts and inconsistencies between multiple sessions.

Comment: @PushpendraSingh Yes, I agree. We solving it so that if frontend detects "No such entity with cartID = null" the reloads the page which customer gets the correct session id and can proceed further.